# ASP.NET web control panel for a desktop application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a C# windows application but I'd like to create a website to be hosted on the same machine that could provide monitoring, other people on the network would be able to login and see the state of certain variables, maybe trigger methods to turn things on and off. I'm looking for a point in the right direction as to how I'd go about doing this?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: I'm just reading about WCF Services, am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using an embedded web server if you don't want to get into running IIS or IIS Express

Comment: Ah so the application would provide the web pages, sounds interesting... to google! Thanks